# LINQ Checking for Nulls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nullable

How do I check Nulls in Linq?

I have a third-party code that returns a `DataTable` with a column type `DateTime` that is nullable.

My code:

```
 var profile = (from d in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
               select new User
               {
                 FirstName = d["FirstName"].ToString(), 
                 Birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(d["BirthDate"].ToString())
               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns an error that the `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types` on the `Birthdate=` statement.

I tried using the following code but returns a cast exception (Cannot cast from string to DateTime?)

```
Birthdate = (DateTime?)d["BirthDate"].ToString();
```

Is there a way to short-hand checking the null values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tested this, but you can try the following:

```
Birthdate = d.Field<DateTime?>("BirthDate")
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx):

> The Field method provides support for accessing columns as nullable types.  If the underlying value in the DataSet is [DBNull.]Value, the returned nullable type will have a value of null.

Comment: +1 as this is what DataSetExtenions was built for; Linq access to DataSets.

Comment: This work great. But when I have an object as a property, for example, `User.Location` and the `Location` object has an `ID` property, the code `User.Location.Id = d.Field<int?>("LocationId")` fails. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function to check the value for `DBNull`, as follows:

```
private static DateTime? ConvertNullableToDateTime(object val) {
    return (val != null && val != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToDateTime(val.ToString()) : null;
}
```

Now you can use this method in your LINQ query:

```
var profile = (from d in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
           select new User
           {
             FirstName = d["FirstName"].ToString(), 
             Birthdate = ConvertNullableToDateTime(d["BirthDate"])
           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I guess there are more than one way to tackle the problem. I also thought about using an Extension method but that didn't work well. I cannot extend the drow["Column"] of the DataTable. Another way was to use the `as` keyword, but I guess I can't use that in a Linq statement

Answer (score 0):

I have got error while I used the above code.  I think we can use the below code.

```
Birthdate = dr["BirthDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime)dr["BirthDate"];
```

If we use `Convert.ToString(dr["BirthDate"])`, then it convert to empty string, if it has DBNull.

Try that also.